# Jetty closing async http requests properly and not leaving horrible amounts of sleeping threads around

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

My application uses embedded Jetty as the http interface, and it seems to hang after 2-3 weeks of uptime. Upon inspection there were a lot of sleeping threads, so I ran it locally with jvisualvm and pounded it out with pyplot and bunch of simple gets and found the number of threads always rises, with most of them sleeping.

My code specifically handles async requests with async context with an async listener, and basically sleeps intermittently until it finds results in a results hash populated by the main app. If the result never shows up, the request times out.

A coworker suggested I may not be closing the requests properly. Is this the case? I've attached my code below for your criticism (after the jvisualvm plot). Thanks!

[image: jvvm]

jetty server:

```
public class APIRequestHandler extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -446741424265391138L;

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<APIMessage> queue;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector;
    private int timeout;
    private Logger logger;
    private Selector selector;

    public APIRequestHandler(Logger logger, Selector selector, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<APIMessage> queue,
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector, int timeout)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.selector = selector;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.collector = collector;
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws java.io.IOException
            {

        String rid = req.getParameter("rid");
        String targetId = req.getParameter("id");
        String msg = req.getParameter("json");

        logger.info("requestId: "+rid);
        logger.info("targetId: "+targetId);
        logger.info("json: "+msg);

        // Send to channel
        APIMessage m = new APIMessage();
        m.rid = rid;
        m.id = targetId;
        m.json = msg + "\r\n";

        // create the async context, otherwise getAsyncContext() will be null
        final AsyncContext ctx = req.startAsync();

        // set the timeout
        ctx.setTimeout(this.timeout);
        ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("rid",rid);
        ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("startTime",System.currentTimeMillis()); // start time

        // set up selector/queue
        queue.add(m);
        this.selector.wakeup();

        // attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext
        ctx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                log("onComplete called");

                // NOTE: errors and timeouts are handled with other events.
                // Successful comm with plug handled by AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor.

                ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();

                // Do the response
                HttpServletResponse ctxRes = (HttpServletResponse)event.getAsyncContext().getResponse();

                int httpStatusCode = (Integer) asyncContextReq.getAttribute("status");
                long startTime = (Long) asyncContextReq.getAttribute("startTime");
                long endTime = (Long) asyncContextReq.getAttribute("endTime");
                long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

                ctxRes.setStatus(httpStatusCode);
                ctxRes.setContentType("application/json");

                ctxRes.getWriter().println("{");
                ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"rid\":"+"\""+ctx.getRequest().getParameter("rid")+"\"");
                ctxRes.getWriter().println(",");
                ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"rtime\":"+elapsedTime); // milliseconds
                ctxRes.getWriter().println(",");
                ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"startTime\":"+"\""+startTime/1000L+"\""); // unix time
                ctxRes.getWriter().println(",");
                ctxRes.getWriter().println("\"response\": "+event.getAsyncContext().getRequest().getAttribute("response"));

                ctxRes.getWriter().println("}");
                ctxRes.getWriter().flush();

            }
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                log("onTimeout called");

                // gateway timeout (on plug request)
                ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("endTime",System.currentTimeMillis());
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("status",504); // request timeout
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("response", "{}");
            }
            public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                log("onError called");

                ServletRequest asyncContextReq = event.getAsyncContext().getRequest();
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("endTime",System.currentTimeMillis());
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("status",500); // request timeout
                asyncContextReq.setAttribute("response", "{}");
            }
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                log("onStartAsync called");
            }
        });

        // spawn some task in a background thread
        ctx.start(new AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor(ctx,collector,logger));
    }
}
```

Async HTTP Request Processor:

```
public class AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor implements Runnable {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> collector;
    private Logger logger;
    private AsyncContext ctx;
        //Defined this here because of strange behaviour when running junit
        //tests and the response json string being empty...
    private String responseStr = null;

    public AsyncHTTPRequestProcessor(AsyncContext _ctx, 
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> _collector, Logger _logger) {
        ctx = _ctx;
        collector = _collector;
        logger = _logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String rid = (String) ctx.getRequest().getAttribute("rid");
        int elapsed = 0;

        while(elapsed<1000)
        {
            if(collector.containsKey(rid)){
                responseStr = collector.get(rid);
                collector.remove(rid);

                logger.info("--->API http request found response in collector!");

                ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("status",200);
                ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("response", responseStr);
                ctx.getRequest().setAttribute("endTime",System.currentTimeMillis());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ctx.complete();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you increment the `elapsed` counter in the processor? Looks like there is a chance that a certain processor will never finish...

Comment: godammit! upon initial inspection, that appears to be the problem.

Comment: Interestingly enough Jetty appears to behave differently on OSX vs Ubuntu for the ctx.getRequest().setAttribute(*), which caused me all sort of problems until 2am!!!